# What is the difference between cross-platform and multi-platform?

Tags: cross-platform, multiplatform

Can someone clearly explain the difference between the terms of *cross-platform* and *multiplatform*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross Platform is where the host development architecture is different than the target execution platform. In short, the target application will not execute on the host development system.

Multi Platform is where a different executable target can be built that will also execute on the host.

Example 1 - You can cross develop from 64 bit linux to 64 Bit Windows using Wine.

Example 2 - You can compile an application for 32 bit Linux using multilib that will execute on 64 bit Linux using the native Linux compiler and using the -m32 switch to build the 32 bit application.

Example 3 - You can target 32 bit Windows applications from Linux 64 if you install Wine32 in addition to Wine and generate both the targets from the same source base if you are using the right toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

**Cross-platform** development aims to create software that runs on various platforms or operating system with a significant difference in architecture. These platforms can include **desktop operating systems** like Windows, macOS, and Linux, as well as **mobile operating systems** like Android and iOS.

**Multiplatform** development focuses on creating software for similar platforms that **share common characteristics** and may require minor adaptations. For example, distinct versions of a single operating system (Windows 7, Windows 10) or hardware platform variations (Android devices with different screen sizes) or different web browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari).